# Openfire and Spark : unable to connect

Tags: active-directory, connection, openfire, jitsi

We installed the last version (4.2.3) of Openfire on locahost to test it before run in production in our local domain.

**When we try to connect** with Spark 2.7.7, Spark 2.8.3 or even tried another client like Jitsi 2.10.5550, **it responds "wrong username or password"**.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nNTw.png]

- Server is up and running.
- Administration interface available on port 9090
- It is correctly linked to our Active Directory database.
- Firewall is disabled on local machine
- Tried to connect both from localhost and another computer on same LAN.

Raw sent packets :

```
<stream:stream to="demo-300" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" version="1.0">
<starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
<stream:stream to="demo-300" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" version="1.0">
<iq id="nmonD-0" type="get"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:auth"><username>cba</username></query></iq>
<iq id="nmonD-1" type="get"><ping xmlns='urn:xmpp:ping' /></iq>
```

Raw received packets :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="server.domain.local" id="p2cgyfth7" xml:lang="en" version="1.0">
    <stream:features>
        <starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"></starttls>
        <mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
            <mechanism>GSSAPI</mechanism>
        </mechanisms>
        <compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress">
            <method>zlib</method>
        </compression>
        <ver xmlns="urn:xmpp:features:rosterver"/>
    </stream:features>
    <proceed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="server.domain.local" id="p2cgyfth7" xml:lang="en" version="1.0">
    <stream:features><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
        <mechanism>GSSAPI</mechanism>
    </mechanisms>
    <compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress">
        <method>zlib</method>
    </compression>
    <ver xmlns="urn:xmpp:features:rosterver"/></stream:features>

and on every minute : 

    <iq type="error" id="1rCcI-3" to="server.domain.local/p2cgyfth7">
        <ping xmlns="urn:xmpp:ping"></ping>
        <error code="401" type="auth">
            <not-authorized xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
        </error>
    </iq>
```

Server configuration :

[image: https://i.imgur.com/R6QWg7p.jpg]

Does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to change `sasl.mechs` setting to `PLAIN` instead of `GSSAPI`

[image: https://i.imgur.com/Wd0vTRX.png]

*But I don't really know why!
Because on client side, it uses `GSSAPI` poperty to connect to server !*